# ¿Por qué el while en Bash elimina los espacios a principio de cada línea?

Tags: bash

Tengo un fichero, concretamente con la salida de un `iptables -v -L`, en el que quiero procesar línea a línea, para modificar si quisiera, algunas líneas.

Como podéis comprobar, la salida de este comando presenta las columnas de la izquierda alineadas a la derecha, y viceversa, consiguiendo gran visibilidad:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 36220 packets, 4308K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
99710  165M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                     
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x37
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x29
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
```

Pero al mostrarlas línea a línea, con el clásico:

```
cat FILE | while read L; do echo "$L"; done
```

alinea las columnas a la izquierda, modificando todo el aspecto con respecto al original:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 36220 packets, 4308K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
99710  165M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x37
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x29
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
```

He probado con `echo "$L"` y con `printf "%s\n" "$L"`, pero en ningún caso evito el alineado a la derecha, es decir, que la línea no se muestra tal cual está en la original.

¿Sabéis alguna forma de evitar esto?

Comment: Échale un ojo a [Use bash to read line by line and keep space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314111).

Comment: Correcto. No se me habia ocurrido el tema de IFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema no está en el `echo` o el `printf`. El problema, tal y como te indicarion en los comentarios, reside en cómo estás leyendo el contenido del fichero. En concreto, en el uso (o no uso) de `IFS`.

**Si `IFS` no está definido, se "come" los espacios que haya a principio y final de línea**. Lo que tienes que hacer es definirlo como valor vacío, esto es, como `IFS=''`, `IFS=""` o `IFS=`:

```
while IFS= read -r linea;
do
     # ... cosas con "$linea"
done < fichero
```

#### ¿Qué es *IFS*?

`IFS` es el *Internal Field Separator*, separador interno de campos. Este parámetro nos interesa en el contexto de tu pregunta para entender cómo el `while` está leyendo el fichero.

#### ¿Cómo lo definimos?

IFS afecta a cómo se realiza la separación en palabras. ¿Cómo? Sí, veamos un ejemplo:

```
$ while IFS=' ' read -r p1 p2; do echo "p1='$p1' -- p2='$p2'"; done <<< "hola qué tal"
p1='hola' -- p2='qué tal'
```

Aquí definimos el IFS como un espacio. De esta manera, la línea que le pasamos (*hola qué tal*) se descompone teniendo en cuenta que lo que separa es un espacio. Por tanto, empieza a leer la línea en "hola" y lo va cargando en la variable `$p1`. Se encuentra un espacio y salta a la siguiente variable `$p2` y ahí guarda todo el resto.

Fíjate que incluso podemos decir que la letra "l" (L minúscula) sea el separador:

```
$ while IFS='l' read -r p1 p2; do echo "p1='$p1' -- p2='$p2'"; done <<< "hola qué tal"
p1='ho' -- p2='a qué ta'
```

Y así las "l"s desaparecen porque *son* el criterio de separación de las palabras.

Volviendo al ejemplo que nos trata, definámoslo como vacío proporcionando además una cadena que contiene espacios delante y detrás:

```
$ while IFS= read -r p1 p2; do echo "p1='$p1' -- p2='$p2'"; done <<< "  hola qué tal   "
p1='  hola qué tal   ' -- p2=''
```

Como ves, los espacios se mantienen, mientras que si lo quitamos se pierden:

```
$ while read -r p1 p2; do echo "p1='$p1' -- p2='$p2'"; done <<< "  hola qué tal   "
p1='hola' -- p2='qué tal'
```

---

Lecturas recomendadas:

- [What is IFS in context of for looping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16195/40596)
- [What does IFS= do in this bash loop: `cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do … done`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/1983854)
- [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26830/40596)

---

Por otra parte, dices que utilizas la sintaxis:

```
cat FILE | while read L; do echo "$L"; done
```

Es recomendable que dejes de usar `cat` pues puede provocarte errores a la larga. Cuando haces `cat | while ...`, el `while` se ejecuta en una subshell. Esto quiere decir que las variables que definas ahí dentro se perderán una vez termine.

Ejemplo:

```
$ visto=0
$ cat f | while read linea; do visto=1; done
$ echo "$visto"
0
```

La variable `$visto` se ha definido a `1` en el bucle pero al terminar sigue valiendo lo que valía al principio.

Por tanto, es mejor esta manera de recorrer un fichero consistente en enchufarle una input con `<`:

```
while IFS= read -r linea;
do
     # ... cosas con "$linea"
done < fichero
```

Fíjate que así sí se modifica la variable en la shell principal:

```
$ visto=0
$ while read linea; do visto=1; done < f
$ echo "$visto"
1
```

También puedes usar el bucle leyendo directamente desde un comando usando la [sustitución de procesos](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/2647/process-substitution#t=201705291201434950319):

```
while IFS= read -r linea;
do
     # ... cosas con "$linea"
done < <(iptables -v -L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como se indica en el [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space/7314111#7314111) compartido por [Trauma en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73812/alineado-de-echo-en-bash#comment135534_73812). Lo que hace falta es redefinir `IFS`, con un simple:

```
IFS=''
```

Y entonces la línea se muestra tal cual.

Comment: Jeje. No se pueden puntuar los comentarios. Si las respuestas. +1 xD.

Comment: @Trauma Es lo mismo, solo que no se puede dar voto en contra.